# user defined constructor not called when i used parenthesis after the object name

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"inside constructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A object1;
    A object2();
}
```

Running above code gave below output

```
$./class.out
inside constructor
```

Here, only for `object1` creation user defined constructor called and not for `object2`. what might be the reason here for not calling user defined constructor in the latter case?

Comment: @Evg -- this is not the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It is simply a function declaration.

Comment: @PeteBecker And why is it a function declaration and not a value-initialized variable of type `A`?

Comment: @Evg — because that’s what the parsing rules say.

Comment: @PeteBecker This looks like the same thing, only the context is slightly different. People seem to customarily refer to this scenario as the most vexing parse, too. For example, Jason Turner considers exactly the same example in his [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByKf_foSlXY) on the most vexing parse. I guess to be technically correct we should omit "the most".

Comment: @Evg — you’re right that people often ignore context and, consequently, misapply terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A object2();` declares a function called `object2` that takes no arguments and returns an `A`. It doesn't create an `A` object called `object2`.

You can either use `A object2;` like you did with `object1`, or `A object2{};` to do what you want.

Comment: Or `auto object2 = A();`, which is in fact one of the major arguments for *always* using `auto` declarations: it massively reduces syntactic edge cases and therefore reduces these errors, and makes it unnecessary to waste constant brain power having to think about this.